# Java Servlet -> Static Graph in Hashmap with non-static Attributes

Tags: java, servlets, graph, static, routes

I've got a large graph wich is processed in a Java Servlet for routing purpose. The Graph has got 100k+ Nodes so I can't reload it for every new call. At the moment the graph is loaded once from my database into the RAM and referenced in a Hashmap.

When I start the servlet (creating a new instance) I need to find the startnode in the graph by id. Therefore I use the hashmap.

That all works very fine.

My problem is, that within my routing task I need to change certain attributes in the graph, i.e. the travelled distance. These attributes of course need to be individual for each created instance. At the moment I handle that task by resetting all "non-static" attributes when creating a new instance. 
That creates two problems.

A) the instances are not thread safe

B) the resetting is very time consuming. Up to 10 times more than the actual routing.

So what I need is a static Hashmap for all instances of my Servlet. This Hashmap needs to contain all nodes of my network. These nodes need to have static attributes like id, coordinates, neighbour nodes etc. but also non-static attributes like travelled distance.

How can I do that?

Thanks for reading and sharing ideas

Comment: When you say "static", I presume you mean "constant".

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be described as a model built at runtime and *instantiated* for every execution of your service.

When you say "static", I presume you mean "constant". The variable attributes are really specific to each execution, not to each Servlet instance. During an execution you should build a separate structure with variable attributes that parallels the constant one. Each node in the variable structure references a single node in the constant structure. The variable structure is built gradually and on demand, as a need for each node arises. The structure is discarded at the end of the execution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just I wonder on how to reference the variable structure from the constant structure. Should I use a "session local" map as ppeterka suggests (using an id to reference)? It should be as quick as possible...

Comment: I supposed it would be enough to reference constant structure from variable structure. You can employ a `ThreadLocal` variable that the constant structure knows about, and which points to the variable structure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, though, that you can (and probably should) refactor so that all the code resides in the variable structure and the fixed structure does not need to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise to keep the "main graph" in RAM in a singleton manner - as Marko Topolnik advised, but I'd keep a Map of only the changed nodes per each session, without the hierarchy, just storing them by ID's (if applicable, per se)

- when a session ends, you only have to discard the map in the session, and that's all.
- when a new session begins, just create a new Map instance...
- You could also pool these maps, if that is critical - but avoid premature optimalization, as it causes far more problems than what it avoids.
- if you need to access a node, fetch it from the original Map, then look it up if it exists in the "session local" map, then merge data in the two if found. (or, if you store the full node, not just the changed atributes in the "session local" map, use the changed node from that map)
- also, be careful, this has many places that can introduce memory leaks...

Comment: Thanks a lot for both quick responses. So from what both of you say it is not possible to use objects in the graph that hold both constant and session dependent attributes. So the way to do would be building a (hash) map that holds "shadow" nodes referenced by the nodes id. That map would be deleted after each session ends.

Comment: @Yojimbo: If you'd like to do that at all costs, you could put a Map<SessionId,ObjectChanges> field into each and every node, which would store the changes, but that would be a big problem... 1. Ugly. 2. unmaintainable. 3. infinite amount of memory leaks. 4. probably would use more resources than anything else...

Yes, I'd advise the use of these __shadow__ maps (nice term for this, I like it!) for each session.

Comment: I agree that the ides of Map<Sessionid, Changes> would be very ugly. As it is supposed to be a web service we'd end up with big maps in every node. So I guess I'll try to build a "shadow" map for each session. Although I really wonder how efficient this is going to be as I have to read that map for every node I pass...

Comment: @Yojimbo: as the session maps will be relatively small (at least that is what I assume from what you wrote), I don't see a performance issue here.

Comment: relatively small means here around 100k readings and writings. The slow resetting mechanism I use at the moment takes about 100ms. The actual routing algrithm is executed in 10 to 40 ms. But I guess I'll try to implement the shadow map and let you know how fast it is ;)